# How do I compute a Groebner Base of a system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to verify that a system of equations has a non empty set of solutions in Matlab. I know that this can be done by computing the Groebner base, and if that is equal to one then the system has an empty solution set. Can I do this in Matlab and how?

Answer (score 2):

You have to build a vector with the set of polynomials. This must be a string of the form

```
 f1 , f2, ..., fn
```

where `f1, f2, ..., fn` are the polynomias , e.g. `f1=x^2-1`, `f2=y*x^3-x-2` . This MUST be a string. You can construct it from an cell array of polynomials e.g. `polyCell={f1, f2, ..., fn}` with

```
polyRing = strcat(polyCell{:});
polyRing(end)=[];
```

Then you should make a call to the appropriate function in **Mupad** with

```
groebnerBasis=evalin(symengine,['groebner::gbasis([' polyRing '])']);
```

or to evaluate with lexicographic order :

```
groebnerBasis=evalin(symengine,['groebner::gbasis([' polyRing '],LexOrder)']);
```

That's it. You may want to use Mupad directly, as well, but I'll let you check the documentation.

Comment: This is executed in mupad? but I don't have it installed.

Comment: Mupad is the default symbolic engine in Matlab, it is installed with  Matlab.

Comment: but how do you define the order of variables, e.g. x>y>z. And/or how can the `feval` function be used?