# Groebner Base algorithm for Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, polynomials, groebner-basis

I want to find a code or general algorithm to calculate the Groebner Basis of polynomials for Octave. I tried this: [How do I compute a Groebner Base of a system of equations in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759135/how-do-i-compute-a-groebner-base-of-a-system-of-equations-in-matlab) but I get thr following error:

`error: strcat: inputs must be strings or cells of strings error: called from strcat at line 105 column 7 test at line 2 column 9`

Does the code work only on Matlab? How can I make it work for Octave?

Comment: It says that your inputs are not strings. Unless we can see your inputs, we can’t answer. Please post a [mre].